# OpenCV crosscompilation paths

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, cross-compiling

I have tested a programs from Myzhars tutorial for jetsonNano + FLIR thermocamera (https://github.com/Myzhar/Lepton3_Jetson)
I can succesfully run cmake and make on the target platform (jetson nano), however I would like to be able to crosscompile from my x86_64 linux PC.

I have (for start) mounted the Jetson to /mnt/sysroot via `sudo sshfs -o follow_symlinks jetson@nano:/ /mnt/sysroot and naive as I am I have expected, I have supposed that from now on setting crosscompilation will be easy. I have modified my cmakelist.txt so it now looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.14)

project (lepton3_jetson)

set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES "Debug;Release" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX "_d")

#########################################################
# FLAGS
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
#########################################################


#crossCompile
set(sysroot /mnt/sysroot)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set (CMAKE_SYSROOT, ${sysroot})
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${sysroot})

set(tools /opt/linaro/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${tools}/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${tools}/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++)
set(CROSSBIN ${tools})

# search for programs in the build host directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
# for libraries and headers in the target directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} --sysroot=${sysroot}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} --sysroot=${sysroot}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS} --sysroot=${sysroot}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS} --sysroot=${sysroot}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)


#crossCompile end

# Letpon3 Library source code
add_subdirectory (grabber_lib)

# OpenCV demo
add_subdirectory (opencv_demo)

# Check Fever App
add_subdirectory (check_fever_app)

# Qt ZED app
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(ZED 3)

if(Qt5_FOUND AND ZED_FOUND)
   add_subdirectory(qt_check_fever)
endif()
```

However, I can't seem to get it running the way I would like to. Currently, with this version of cmake, I am getting error

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:165 (message):
  Could NOT find BLAS (missing: BLAS_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:458 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBLAS.cmake:947 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  /mnt/sysroot/usr/local/zed/zed-config.cmake:36 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:53 (find_package)


CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:53 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /mnt/sysroot/usr/local/zed/zed-config.cmake

  but it set ZED_FOUND to FALSE so package "ZED" is considered to be NOT
  FOUND.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
`
```

Am I reading correctly that it tries to find the libraries on the host instead of target?

And why?

Comment: Lines between "#crossCompile" and "#crossCompile end" should be part of the [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling), used via `cmake` option `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=<...>`. Placing these lines in the `CMakeLists.txt` after the `project()` call is **wrong**.

Comment: Oh, thanks. So I have moved those lines into a separate file, and I am calling the cmake with the option. No change in functionality though.

Comment: The line `set (CMAKE_SYSROOT, ${sysroot})` should be without comma. Note, that with correct setting of `CMAKE_SYSROOT` CMake **automatically** interprets it as one of `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` and **automatically** adds `--sysroot` option for the compiler.

Comment: Thank you. My inexperience with cmake is beginnign to be apparanent, isn't it. However - comma removed, still the same result :(

Comment: My (temporary) solution: I have Jetson mounted to /mnt/sysroot. I have two sets of makefiles - with one, I can compile on the target device (jetson) and woth other the Qt creator on the host is able to parse (but not compile) the project.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with similar problem: i did never get to fully working solution.
I did, however, managed to create cmakefile which allowed me to at least parse the project with IDE on my host computer and then compile it on target.

Comment: But this is a comment rather than an answer? I think you can amend your question with a comment like this.